# Transfer folder(rootfs) via tftp into craneboard

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cortex-a8, tftp

I've transfer file(uImage)via TFTP into craneboard.Now i want to transfer **rootfs** (folder) into craneboard.

Is it possible using tftp?
U-image can be loaded successfully.[tftp tranfer uImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLEdk.png)

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What is running on your board that is the TFTP client?  U-Boot or Linux w/initramfs?  What kind of rootfs? Ramfs or UBIFS or JFFS2 or ???  Is it an image or tar or ???  How large is it compared to free RAM?  What are you going to do with this rootfs after it has been transferred?

Comment: I've inserted Uboot.img file and MLO.And tftp service is enabled.Using JFFS2 file system.It is tar file.And its size around 8MB.There is 120MB free RAM.Actually,I'm trying to start Kernel without using SD card slot.